# How to get data and change theme of Activity on which card.io is integrated?

Tags: android, themes, card.io

I am integrating card.io in my app for reading information of debit/credit card. I have integrated it successfully but it is always getting card number but not expiry, CVV and display.It sometimes get expiry date but it never gets card holder name and cvv. And further more if I want to change theme I mean text fields and button backgrounds are those possible as library classes not editable. Below is the code I am using for intent i.e,

```
private void readCardInfo() {
    Intent scanIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CardIOActivity.class);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CARDHOLDER_NAME, true);
    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and below is the code I am using for getting data on onActivityResult();

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE ){
        if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
            CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);
            cardNumber = scanResult.getFormattedCardNumber();
            if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
                expiryDate = scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear;
                LogHelper.debugLog("expiry date is " + expiryDate);
                setExpiryDate(expiryDate);
            }
            if (scanResult.cvv != null) {
                codeCVV = scanResult.cvv;
                tvCVV.setText(codeCVV);
            }
            if (scanResult.cardholderName != null) {
                cardHolderName = scanResult.cardholderName;
                etNameOnCard.setText(cardHolderName);
            }
            setCardNumber(cardNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing wrong something or missing any step?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late replied But if someone face same problem then it will helpful

EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME
public static final String EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME
Boolean extra. Optional. If this value is set to true, and the application has a theme, the theme for the card.io Activitys will be set to the theme of the application.

pass EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME constant in intent extra and set boolean value to true.